# quick apply email register, login auth for django

Tags: django, authentication, redis

I'd like to have a quick apply user auth in Django. required function:

1. email register and actition, with image CAPTCHA to keep away spam robot.
2. unique userid increasing, map to unique email.
3. log in/out, Authentication cache
4. password persist

I'm looking into django-auth, django-register, django-simple-captcha. Meanwhile hopping anyone suggest a quick solution.

redis is preferred to store user data.

Answer (score 2):

i personally recommend

[DJANGO-ALLAUTH](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth)

because its well documented